# calculate marginal PDF from joint PDF of dependent random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, density-function, marginal-distribution

The marginal PDF $f_X(x)$ can be calculated as
$$f_X(x)=\int f_{X,Y}(x,y)dy=\int f_{X|Y}(x|y)f_Y(y)dy \tag{1}$$

However, I stuck in a particular case as follows.

$\mathbf{X}=[X_1,X_2]$ is uniform point on a circle having radius $R$. The radius $R$ is also a random variable with pdf $f_R(r)$.

The uniform distribution means $f_{X_1,X_2|R=r}(x_1,x_2|r)=\frac{1}{2\pi r}$ where $2 \pi r$ is circumference.

Hence $f_{X_1,X_2,R}(x_1,x_2,r)=\frac{1}{2\pi r} \times f_R(r) \tag{2}$.

**As my purpose is to calculate $f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)$**, I use marginal pdf property

$$f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2) = \int f_{X_1,X_2,R}(x_1,x_2,r)dr= \int \frac{1}{2\pi r} f_R(r) dr \tag{3}$$

The integral of a function of $r$ over the domain of $r$ will be something that does not depend on $r$. Finally, $f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)$ does not depend on $r$ and because $r$ is the only variable, $f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)$ is constant. This must be wrong.

**Question 1: Could anyone please show me where I was wrong and how to fix it?**

*Updated*

I tried another way
$$f_{X_1,X_2,R}(x_1,x_2,r) = f_{R|X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2}(r|x_1,x_2) f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2) = \delta\left(R=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}\right) f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)\tag{4}$$
where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function.

**Question 2: How could I derive $f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)$ from $f_{X_1,X_2,R}(x_1,x_2,r)$?**

Comment: You shouldn’t get something that depends on $r$ for $f_{X_1, X_2}(x_1, x_2)$ in the same way that $f_X(x)$ doesn’t depend on $y$. Right? You integrated out all the possible values to find the marginal pdf of $\bf{X}$. But the key is that you used $f_R(r)$ in your calculation of that pdf, so it actually does depend on the distribution of $R$.

Comment: @JonBown Thanks for answer, but I don't get what you mean. I do expect that $f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)$ depends on $R$ because of rotational symmetry. However, I do not expect that $f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)$ is constant.

Comment: But uniform random variables should give constant probabilities, and you’re integrating over the possible values of $R$, so depending on the pdf of $R$ you’ll get values for the pdf of $\bf{X}$ that depend on the $R$. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: @JonBown yes that makes sense. However, how could we derive $f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)$ from $f_{X_1,X_2,R}(x_1,x_2,r)$? Is it simply $f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2) = f_{X_1,X_2,R}(x_1,x_2,r)$ like what I have just updated the question?

Comment: Note that $$f_{X_1,X_2|R=r}(x_1,x_2|r)=\frac{1}{2\pi r} 1_{x_1^2 + x_2^2 = r^2}$$

Comment: Note that, conditionally on $R=r$, the random vector $(X_1,X_2)$ **has no PDF** hence any solution starting from the undefined object $$f_{X_1,X_2\mid R=r}$$ is bound to be wrong mathematically speaking.

Answer (score 0):

Since

$$f_{X_1,X_2|R=r}(x_1,x_2|r)=\frac{1}{2\pi r} 1_{x_1^2 + x_2^2 = r^2}$$

You have that

$$f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2) = \int f_{X_1,X_2,R}(x_1,x_2,r)dr= \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{2\pi r} f_R(r) 1_{x_1^2 + x_2^2 = r^2}dr $$

The integrand is equal to $0$ whenever $r \neq \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2}$. So the integral is simply

$$f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)  = \frac{1}{2\pi \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2}} f_R\left(\sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2}\right)$$

Comment: Great answer. However, what if I replace the random variable radius $R$ by its squared value $Z=R^2$?

$$f_{X_1,X_2|Z=z}(x_1,x_2|z)=\frac{1}{2\pi \sqrt{z}} 1_{x_1^2 + x_2^2 = z}$$

Then

$$f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2) = \int f_{X_1,X_2,Z}(x_1,x_2,z)dz= \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{2\pi \sqrt{z}} f_Z(z) 1_{x_1^2 + x_2^2 = z}dz $$
By the same reasoning,
$$f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2) = \frac{1}{2\pi \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2}} f_Z(x_1^2 + x_2^2)$$

I should expect that $f_Z(x_1^2 + x_2^2)= f_R\left(\sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2}\right)$, right? But I find a case that shows this is not true.

Comment: Now I take a particular distribution that $R$ follows non central chi distribution of $k$ degrees of freedom and non central paramater $\lambda$, then $Z=R^2$ follows non central chi squared distribution with $k$ degrees of freedom and parameter $\lambda^2$.

Hence
$$f_R(r) = e^{-(r^2+\lambda^2)/2} r^{k/2} \lambda^{1-k/2} I_{k/2-1}(\lambda r)$$
$$f_R(\sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2}) = e^{-(x_1^2 + x_2^2+\lambda^2)/2} (x_1^2 + x_2^2)^{k/4} \lambda^{1-k/2} I_{k/2-1}(\lambda \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2})$$

Comment: $$f_Z(z) = \frac{1}{2} e^{-(z+\lambda^2)/2} \left(\frac{z}{\lambda^2}\right)^{k/4-1/2} I_{k/2-1}(\lambda \sqrt{z})$$
$$f_Z(x_1^2 + x_2^2) = \frac{1}{2} e^{-(x_1^2 + x_2^2+\lambda^2)/2} \left(\frac{x_1^2 + x_2^2}{\lambda^2}\right)^{k/4-1/2} I_{k/2-1}(\lambda \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2})$$

Then I have $f_Z(x_1^2 + x_2^2) = \frac{1}{2} (x_1^2 + x_2^2)^{-1/2} f_R(\sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2}) \neq f_R(\sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2})$.

Sorry for a lot of calculations, but I think I just missed something basic that you can point out easily. Thanks

Comment: Wrong answer, due to a lack of the relevant theoretical foundations. Actually, $$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{2\pi r} f_R(r) 1_{x_1^2 + x_2^2 = r^2}dr=0$$ and not what is written in the post.